# Application Bot on_raw_reaction_add send message in specified channel with payload

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on an application Bot that asks questions in a DM and saves the answers. I just have a small problem and that is I want to send the answers in a specified channel in an embed. but I didn't find and another way than doing it with `await applychannel.send(embed=Embed)`, but that doesn't work it prints an error.

ERROR:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itzbe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\itzbe\Desktop\Discord\Bot\Python Test Object\cogs\command.py", line 85, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await applychannel.send(embed=Embed)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):

        messageID = payload.message_id
        if messageID == 736553190853574769:
            def check(m):
                return m.author == payload.member and m.guild is None and not payload.member.bot

            applychannel = self.client.get_channel(736553190853574769)

            frage1 = 'Wie heißt du in Reallife?'
            frage2 = 'Wie heißt du auf Discord?'
            frage3 = 'Wie lautet dein Name auf Epic?'
            frage4 = 'Wie alt bist du?'
            frage5 = 'Wie viele Arena-Punkte hast du?'
            frage6 = 'Hast du Preisgelder gewonnen?'
            frage7 = 'Für welches Team bewirbst du dich?'

            if payload.emoji.name == '':
                await payload.member.send(frage1)
                answer1 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage2)
                answer2 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage3)
                answer3 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage4)
                answer4 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage5)
                answer5 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage6)
                answer6 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                await payload.member.send(frage7)
                answer7 = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)

                YesOrNo = await payload.member.send('Fertig! Bist du sicher, dass du deine Bewerbung abschicken willst?')
                await YesOrNo.add_reaction('✅')
                await YesOrNo.add_reaction('❌')

                try:
                    reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60.0, check=lambda reaction, user: self.client.user != user)

                    if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
                        Embed = discord.Embed(
                            title=f'Bewerbung von {payload.member}',
                            color=discord.Colour.lighter_grey(),
                            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                            description=f'**{frage1}** \n {answer1.content} \n\n '
                                        f'**{frage2}** \n {answer2.content} \n\n '
                                        f'**{frage3}** \n {answer3.content} \n\n '
                                        f'**{frage4}** \n {answer4.content} \n\n'
                                        f'**{frage5}** \n {answer5.content} \n\n'
                                        f'**{frage6}** \n {answer6.content} \n\n'
                                        f'**{frage7}** \n {answer7.content} \n\n'
                        )

                        await applychannel.send(embed=Embed)
                        await payload.member.send('Gesendet! Wir werden uns in denn naechsten 48 Studen melden, falls nicht bitte melde dich im Support!')
                        return
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    await payload.member.send('Bewerbung wurde unterbrochen!')
                else:
                    await payload.member.send('Bewerbung wurde unterbrochen!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because

```
applychannel = self.client.get_channel(736553190853574769)
```

returns a `NoneType` object. The reason it returns `None` is because `736553190853574769` is an invalid channel id. To fix the problem, try to find the right channel id, then it should work fine.

Comment: do you know how to remove reactions, after a client reacted?

Comment: @ItzBen To be honest, I don't. Sorry.